# How to pass a Notification to the method called by the Observer in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, observer-pattern

I would like to access the Notification object that is sent from the method below.

```
var currentTrack:MPMediaItem? {
    get{
        return playlist?.items[index]
    }
    set{
        print(newValue?.title!)
        //self.index = locateIndex(track: newValue!)
        let notif = Notification.init(name: Playlist.SongChangedName, object:self)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(notif)
    }
}
```

The Notifications name is defined as:

```
static let SongChangedName = Notification.Name("SongChangedNotification")
```

Here is the observer:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(testSelector),
                                           name: Playlist.SongChangedName, //Notification.Name("songChanged"),
                                           object: nil)
}
```

Here is the Method it calls:

```
func testSelector(notification:Notification){

    queueNextTrack()

}
```

How do I pass testSelector a notification object? I know it has something to do with the object parameter of the addObserver method.

Thank you.

Comment: It's in the notification that gets passed to your selector in `notification.object`

Comment: Right. How do i pass that notification into the selector? Where is the reference to the notification in the addObserver method?

Comment: It's already being passed in to your selector, you don't need to do anything else to the `addObserver` method

Comment: Dan, you appear to be correct. I guess I need to understand something about 'selector'. It is different that the testSelector(notification:Notification) works without me directly passing it a notification.

Answer (score 1):

You can now get rid of your problem entirely by not using selectors in your notifications, timers, etc. There are new block based API to replace target-selector such  as

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Playlist.SongChangedName, object: nil, queue: nil, using: { notification in
    self.testSelector(testSelector)
})
```

For the most part you won't need access to the notifications in your blocks so you could do this too

```
func testSelector(){
    queueNextTrack()
}

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Playlist.SongChangedName, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
    self.testSelector()
}
```

or most my preferred in most scenarios:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    let testBlock: (Notification) -> Void = {
        self.queueNextTrack()
    }
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Playlist.SongChangedName, object: nil, queue: nil, using: testBlock)
}
```

**EDIT** I'd also suggest you take a look at the sample code in the description for this API